# why python print an empty line from a file

Tags: python, printing

I read file and print lines using python 2.7.8. But python always prints some extra empty lines.

I use the function:

```
def reverse(x):
    linelist = open(x, 'r').readlines()
    linelist.reverse()
    for line in linelist:
        print line
```

The content in my file is:

> She sells seashells on the seashore;
>
> The shells that she sells are seashells I`m sure.
>
> So if she sells seashells on the seashore,
>
> I`m sure that the shells are seashore shells.

But in the output, the last two print lines have extra empty lines:

> I`m sure that the shells are seashore shells.
>
> So if she sells seashells on the seashore,
>
> ---
>
> The shells that she sells are seashells I`m sure.
>
> ---
>
> She sells seashells on the seashore;
>
> ---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readlines` keeps the newline \n character of every line.
You should use `rstrip` before printing the line:

```
for line in linelist:
    print line.rstrip('\n')
```

Comment: Why the first two lines can print exactly?

Comment: Sorry I did not understand you comment.

Answer (score 0):

readlines gives an extra line by default.
So, try adding a comma(,) after line

for line in linelist:
    print line,

Comment: Why the first two lines can print exactly?